# Wordpress comparing arrays for term (Using AND/OR at same time within Array)?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, if-statement, multidimensional-array

```
$mergedterms = array_unique(array_merge($series_terms, $genres_terms, $rating_terms), SORT_REGULAR);
    foreach($mergedterms as $mergedterm){
  $args2 = array(
        'post_type'=> 
        array('progressive_review', 'game_information','gaming_series', 'dlc_title'),
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby'    => 'rand',
        'post__not_in' => array($currentID, $gametitleID),
        'tax_query' => array( 
              'relation' => 'AND',
         array(
          'relation' => 'OR',
          array(     
            'taxonomy' => 'games_titles',
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => array ($term->name),
    ),
          array( 
             'taxonomy' => 'gaming_genres',
             'field' => 'slug', 
             'terms' => array ($mergedterm->name),
    ),
          array(                
            'taxonomy' => 'game_ratings',
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => array ($mergedterm->name),
    ),
          array(     
            'taxonomy' => 'gaming_series',
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => array ($mergedterm->name),
            ),
        ), array(
            'taxonomy' => 'age_ratings',
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => $age_terms,
            ),
        ),/*Search above post type for taxonomy and if matches then proceed*/
    ); } 

   $the_query = new WP_Query($args2);
    if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    php bm_ignorePost($post->ID);

           php endwhile; else:
           php endif;  wp_reset_postdata();
```

After finding alot of other issues I am now back to this same issue. Therefor I deleted the post and updated the code.

Simply put I cannot for the life of me get the array as 'OR''s but treat the $age_terms as a 'AND'. There surely must be a easy way to accomplish this? Keep hearing array_intersect is rather slow as speed is everything. This is why i have tried multiple methods but cannot see why it cannot be processed within the same array?

```
    Array
(
    [post_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => progressive_review
            [1] => game_information
            [2] => gaming_series
            [3] => dlc_title
        )

    [posts_per_page] => 10
    [post_status] => publish
    [orderby] => rand
    [post__not_in] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1958
            [1] => 1623
        )

    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => games_titles
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Sonic Lost World
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => gaming_genres
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Violence
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => game_ratings
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Violence
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => gaming_series
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Violence
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => age_ratings
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3pegi
                            [1] => 7pegi
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The age_terms come from

```
<?php if (has_term('7pegi', 'age_ratings', $post->ID)){
    $age_terms = array('3pegi', '7pegi'); }?>
```

Introduced a array var to fix issue with merge meaning even better relevance as intended.

```
$genres_sorted = array();
foreach($genres_terms as $genres_term) {
 $genres_sorted[] = $genres_term;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what do You mean. Clarify it.

Comment: use this to make sure the array is merging how you want it to:  `print "<pre>".print_r($mergedterms, true)."</pre>";`

Comment: I also have no idea what you mean.... Can you show what is in the arrays you already have and then show what the output array should look like after the merge/intercept/whatever?  (also, deleting your questions from StackOverflow will really hurt your reputation and may get you banned.  You should edit the questions to clarify stuff instead of deleting them)

Comment: @user623952 I temp removed question due to sorting out the merge issue. The merging works fine in a single array when they are all treated as either a AND/OR. The problem i have is i need the array to run once with a OR then use $age_terms as a AND to remove anything that doesn't have those entries.
Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => age_ratings
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3pegi
                            [1] => 7pegi
                        )

Comment: Update your question with the array information.  It is too hard to read in a comment.  I don't know what you mean by the `or` and `and` stuff... demonstrated it through examples in your post.  Show what you have and then what you want to end up with and the conditions it's based on...